# Don't understand mismatch/throw error for Scanner

Tags: java

I'm setting up a simple day of the month program.  I set up the Scanner as I have in other assignments but Scanner isn't working this time.  I'm getting multiple errors I don't understand.

I've copied and pasted other assignments and I'm not getting their error, and it is pretty simple so I don't see what I could be messing up.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class H3_ken {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int month;
        int year;

        System.out.println("Enter what month you would like to look up: ");
        month = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter what year: ");
        year = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("You have chosen to look up the month of " + month + " in the year of " + year + ".");

    }

}
```

This is the output from entering the month.

```
Enter what month you would like to look up: 
January
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at H3_ken.main(H3_ken.java:12)
```

Comment: `January` isn't an int, is it? You need to enter, e.g. `1`.

Answer (score 3):

If you actually wanted to enter January, you need a string

```
String month = input.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enter strings as months, use `Scanner.nextLine();`.
Because java has data types, You need to adjust your code to it.
For example, you cannot put a number in `String`.

The same goes for Java's Scanner class.
I know you just asked why your String input isn't working, but here are all Scanner input functions so you don't get confused next time:

`nextBoolean()` Reads a boolean value from the user (false or true)

`nextByte()`    Reads a byte value from the user (number between -127 and 127)

`nextDouble()`  Reads a double value from the user (a precise decimal number)

`nextFloat()`   Reads a float value from the user (a less precise version of double)

`nextInt()`     Reads a int value from the user (a number between -2147483647 and 2147483647)

`nextLine()`    Reads a String value from the user

`nextLong()`    Reads a long value from the user (a number between -9.223372e+18 and 9.223372e+18)

`nextShort()`   Reads a short value from the user (a number between -32767 and 32767)

Answer (score -2):

If you enter two int value separated by at least one space this code work correctly!

Probably you have a symbol between year and month (other than space)